# Cauchy Sequence: Multiplication Property

Tags: real-analysis

This is part of my homework, but I could not solve it.

> If $\{x_n\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\{y_n\in\mathbb{R}\}$ are both Cauchy sequences then $\{x_ny_n\}$
>   is Cauchy sequence.

It is easy if I use the fact that $\{t_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if it converges. But without using that fact, how can one solve it?

Edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the inequality

$$|x_ny_n-x_my_m|=|x_ny_n-x_ny_m+x_ny_m-x_my_m|\leq|x_n||y_n-y_m|+|x_n-x_m||y_m|,$$ and note that you will want to use the fact that Cauchy sequences are bounded.

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful!

Comment: @Husain: You're welcome.  What is your easy solution if you can use the fact that a sequence is Cauchy if and only if it converges?

Comment: It is easy to show that $\{x_ny_n\}$ converges if $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ converge.But apparently, it is very similar to your solution. I just couldn't see it.

Comment: @Husain: What easy way to show that do you have in mind?

Comment: The idea would be that we assume that $x_n$ converges to $L_1$ and $y_n$ converges to $L_2$. When you multiply $|x_n-L_1|$ by $|y_n-L_2|$ you get $LHS \le x_n|y_n-L_2| + L_1|y_n-L_2|$. I think it is obvious from there.

Comment: @Husain:  Thank you.  Sorry, but I cannot follow that sketch. Why would you multiply $|x_n-L_1|$ and $|y_n-L_2|$?  What is $LHS$?  Don't you actually want to look at $|x_ny_n-L_1L_2|$?  Doesn't it end up very similar to the problem with Cauchy sequences (except with one fewer index)?

Comment: Ops! Yeah that does not make any sense. I returned to my notes and this was my proof: $|x_ny_n-L_1L_2| = |(x_n-L_1)y_n + L_1(y_n-L_2)| \le |y_n||x_n-L_1| + L_1|y_n-L_2| < \epsilon$. Sorry about that confusion. The solution is very similar to yours.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have an $\epsilon > 0$. We know for any $\epsilon_x > 0, \exists N_x$ s.t. $\forall m,n > N_x, |x_n - x_m| < \epsilon_x$. Similarly, for any $\epsilon_y > 0, \exists N_y$ s.t. $\forall m,n > N_y, |y_n - y_m| < \epsilon_y$.

Now consider $$|x_ny_n - x_my_m| = |x_ny_n - x_ny_m + x_ny_m - x_my_m|$$

$$\leq |x_n||y_n - y_m| + |y_m||x_n - x_m|$$

So if you choose $\epsilon_x < \frac{\epsilon}{2Y}$ and $\epsilon_y < \frac{\epsilon}{2X}$, where $X,Y$ are some upper bounds for the tails of the Cauchy sequences, then choosing the larger of $N_x$ and $N_y$ should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

try this$$|x_ny_n-x_my_m|\le|x_ny_n-x_my_n|+|x_my_n-x_my_m|$$now when taking the common factor you'll have$$|x_ny_n-x_my_m|\le|y_n||x_n-x_m|+|x_m||y_n-y_m|$$now since $x_n$ and $y_n$ are cauchy that means they are bounded which implies that LHS goes to zero as $m,n\to\infty$ and hence $x_ny_n$ is cauchy.