# Sequential continuity in normed linear spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces

I am trying to prove the following "contiuity-type" result.

Let $X,Y$ normed linear spaces. Let $\{T_n\} \to T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ and $\{u_n\} \to u \in X$. Show that $\{T_n(u_n)\} \to \{T(u)\} \in Y$

Any help will be most appreciated! Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think I have proven something like this in the case of real valued functions and sequences of real numbers. Is the proof the same?

Comment: Is the proof the same as what?  Could you please elaborate?  Have you tried something to solve *this* problem, starting with using the definition of $\{T_n(u_n)\}\to T(u)$?

Comment: Replacing the operators by functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \Bbb R$ and the sequences by sequences of real numbers, will the proof of this statement be the same as the statement for which I am asking for help?

Comment: For arbitrary functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$?  Under what topology?  You have not made a precise statement or indicated what the analogous proof is, so I don't know how to answer whether it would be similar.  For this problem, I suggest using the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the inequality

$$\|T_n(u_n)-T(u)\|=\|T_n(u_n)-T_n(u)+T_n(u)-T(u)\|\leq \|T_n\|\|u_n-u\|+\|T_n-T\|\|u\|,$$ and note that you will want to use the fact that convergent sequences are bounded.

(Some text copied from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309869/1424).)